# Pick two integers on a string using Regular expressions and Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string and want to get two integers to save in an array

used this:

```
x= /[0-9]+/.match(dimensions)
dimensions[ /[0-9]+[ ]+/ ] = ""
y= dimensions
```

get the first replace and pick the second

but this dont works fine if the string have one number, the best in store on array is count after

is there any way that can make this easier?

Example strings:

```
5 9

5

sadasd 5 9  assasdadsaas
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but what exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using regex captures would work better?

```
>> dimensions = "asdf 11 22"
=> "asdf 11 22"
>> m = dimensions.match(/([0-9]+)[ ]*([0-9]*)/)
=> #<MatchData "11 22" 1:"11" 2:"22">
>> m.captures
=> ["11", "22"]
>>
?> dimensions = "asdf 11"
=> "asdf 11"
>> m = dimensions.match(/([0-9]+)[ ]*([0-9]*)/)
=> #<MatchData "11" 1:"11" 2:"">
>> m.captures
=> ["11", ""]
```

Comment: captures nice, have used  dimensions[0]  dimensions[1]  and failed